# display text from other file no the mainActivity

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to write to the screen from another file other than the mainActivity file? I can write the the screen in my mainActivity as follows.

MainActivity.java

```
TextView myTextViewTime= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.connected);
myTextViewTime.setText("Hello");
```

but I can't do this from say a file called hell.java

```
  String msg = "hello";
  public void  message_recieve(String msg){
      TextView myTextViewTime= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.connected);
      myTextViewTime.setText("Hello");
   }
```

Comment: that's because findViewById is a method from Activity.

Comment: how can I make it a method for my other java file?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so if you pass the other class a context of your activity.
You can also for communication to occur on the UIThread with the setting of text via a

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                               myTextViewTime.setText("Hello");
                            }
                     });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it still fails even if I try  private TextView input1; input1.setText("");

Comment: Fails how?  Are you getting a null pointer exception?  Perhaps you can provide your output and we can put a quick response in.